# Who should I appoint regents and partners?

Tags: massive-chalice

In Massive Chalice, you can appoint a regent and a partner to a keep. However, there is no explanation of what to look for in a suitable couple, other than to remember that they will be retired from combat.

In the default list, they are sorted by experience ... but I don't know if it's actually important.

As far as I can tell, their **only** purpose is to breed new heroes. Therefore, I tend to pick people with good traits and fertility, and ignore their attributes alltogether. I pick the "best" one as the regent, and the second best one as their mate.

However, I've read other places that the regent is the "dominant" one, but I don't know to what degree. Does it influence their class? Does the partner have any influence at all?

**What considerations should I keep in mind, when appointing regents and partners?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When appointing a regent and their partner, prefer heroes with no relics, as they will keep their relics with them and so out of fights. The stats of the regent will also influence the stats of new heroes in their bloodline, thereby giving an incentive for using powerful heroes as regents. Also don't forget that heroes will die over time, and if they don't have any offsprings their bloodline will be lost with them. So you must consider carefully all of these in order to maximize the usefulness of your heroes.

[Source1](http://massivechalice.wikia.com/wiki/Buildings), [Source2](http://www.pcgamer.com/massive-chalice-hands-on-respect-your-elders-and-dont-marry-your-cousins/)