# What is the point of same-sex partnerships?

Tags: massive-chalice

One of the core concepts in Massive Chalice is that you are cultivating bloodlines of heroes over many generations. As explained in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193512/who-should-i-appoint-regents-and-partners), there are several factors which contribute to how you should assign heroes romantic partners. You're able to assign same-sex partnerships, but these don't seem to produce offspring - that's a pretty big downside. From a gameplay standpoint, is there any reason to assign same-sex partnerships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually not.

Infertile or same-sex couples can still adopt, either through random events or the Adopt a boy/girl project. The child in question will inherit personality traits from both parents.

However, adoption takes time away from other projects and it is rarely worth it just to get the perfect traits. Same-sex couples and adoption should usually be a last resort if too many heroes get killed.

Comment: Downvoter, is there a problem with my answer?